# How close can a launch pad be to a lunar base?

Tags: spaceships, space-constructs

This is for a base that has been built up into a big, complex place. For the radiation safety of long-term residents, the walls are very thick. There are windows, that are quite large. They have quite strong glass, reinforced and double glazed with about half a meter between the panes, so the outer layer acts as Whipple shielding against meteoroids. The rockets are nuclear but their fuel is hydrogen, so there isn't radiation exposure from them. Still, I put the nearest landing pad half a kilometer away in case of explosions. But I wonder if I'm being too conservative.

[image]

The ships do use liquid oxygen in an afterburner design, it's injected into the nozzle just after the throat so it's never exposed to the nuclear reactor. So the ships are carrying LOX and liquid hydrogen, but they are in separate tanks, in a vacuum. (The LOX is in the smaller tank sticking out near the bottom, the LH2 is in the larger tank to the left of it.) Does the low explosion potential of that arrangement allow the launch pad to possibly be even closer? Or does prudence say just never do that? These ships fly themselves - to hit other structures they'd have to be quite off their final approach and their emergency systems would have to all fail. (I don't know that 'self-destruct' is the way to go in this case. Maybe...)

Comment: You assume that the explosion happens on a plane on which you've build the base as well. However geography is a huge factor. If the settlement is in a lava tube or in a crater wall, the rocket could be placed over a ridge and wouldn't do much damage in any case. Distance won't do much against an air burst, especially as all the debris are on pure ballistic trajectories. Point Defense cannons are probably a good idea in any case.

Comment: [Related](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/53927/just-how-unreasonably-gigantic-was-the-exclusion-zone-for-the-scrubbed-spacex) on our sister site [space.se].

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight I just considered it from the perspective of the closest point at which something could go drastically wrong. This is for a game, this decision is for convenience of good visuals and game navigation. I just wonder how reasonable it is.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight I like the idea of point defense cannons... although I also think about the relative risk of having cannons around, versus the risk of a launch or landing failure leading to large impacts.

Comment: "The rockets are nuclear but their fuel is hydrogen, so there isn't radiation exposure from them.": the propellant used doesn't matter, nuclear rockets can't possibly carry enough shielding to shield the reactor in all directions. Typical concepts have them at the far end of a long vehicle, or even on a long truss, so a small shadow shield can protect the sensitive parts of the vehicle. And in the event of an accident, radioactive reactor bits could be spread across quite a large area, especially in lunar gravity...not something you want scattered around your base.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff From my research it is possible to shield a reactor adequately in almost all directions, the only gap being the nozzle throat, which gets a plug put in it on landing. If you disagree you'd have to take it up with [Juhn Bucknell](https://www.thespaceshow.com/guest/john-bucknell).  I am aware of the very long thin designs you speak of - they feature a huge number of radiators as well, so I'm guessing that's part of nuclear electric designs. And I can't see how these could explode, how the LOX and LH2 could ever form an explosive mixture.

Comment: @kimholder That's absolutely not the case. It's not an issue of geometry at all (and there'd be no reason for a gap through the nozzle if it were), it's a matter of mass. Anything but a shadow shield wastes mass by shielding areas that don't protect the crew and spacecraft. And no, this is the approach used for nuclear thermal and nuclear electric systems. And you don't need LOX at all. Apart from the possibility of an explosive failure of the NTR pressure vessel, a failed landing could result in an impact that's easily energetic enough to scatter the vehicle in pieces across the landscape.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I would need a reference for this. I've been told by people I feel know what they are doing that this system will work fine. The LOX is an afterburner system called (LANTR)[http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2017/ph241/mangram2/docs/2004-0182399.pdf]. It raises thrust and allows the use of a smaller reactor. The extra shielding mass is supposed to be feasible.  The base is capable of handling the kinds of failures you mention. I'd have to dig into my references to say more.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I've been reviewing my reference material, and a couple of further new papers. If it please you, I'd appreciate the opportunity to talk with you a bit about this at some point. I had banked (I think - I don't really recall) on flagrant waste of LOX to increase thrust through the afterburner to justify the design. I made the rocket a long time ago. I'm now completely rethinking it, and wondering how best to redesign both the spaceport and the rocket. I'll look to ask questions about it, but I think it might be good to get my bearings with a knowledgeable person first.

Comment: LANTR does not allow shielding in all directions...that PDF even shows vehicles with shadow shields. Shielding is heavy, and there's no sense spending the mass to block radiation that would go harmlessly into empty space. Any mass spent on such shielding is mass not spent providing better protection to the vehicle and its payload/crew. Worse, it would impede direct radiation of heat and increase the thermal load on the vehicle.

Comment: LANTR is not a great fit for lunar vehicles anyway...the LOX-augmentation is a trade of specific impulse for added thrust, and you don't need lots of thrust for a vehicle designed to operate on the moon. Of course, nuclear engines are bad for landing anyway, due to their poor throttle control and the radiological issues involved in working around them after they've been active.

Answer (score 4):

The velocity of a detonation wave in a suitable hydrogen-oxygen mix is probably not going to be higher than [about 2km/s](http://www.hyresponse.eu/files/Lectures/Dealing_with_hydrogen_explosions_notes.pdf) for a well mixed cloud with ideal fuel-oxideser proportions, and what you'll be dealing with is not going to be a well mixed cloud. Lets take that as a worst case figure.

Bits of debris are not likely to come firing out of the blast any faster than that. The blast is going to be approximately spherical, which means that most of the shrapnel will not be heading towards your viewpoint. It'll arrive as a cloud of irregularly shaped chunks of lightweight metal and composites.

This compares favourably with the speed that you might be expecting meteor strikes to have, which could come in a *lot* faster than that... up to 72km/s, in the extreme.

The minimum safe separation distance, then, is a function of how much energy your windows can absorb per unit area, and some model of the most dangerous bits of debris coming out of the explosion. That seems entirely too hard to work out, as far as I'm concerned, but with suitably over-engineered windows you could handwave almost any distance away.

> does prudence say just never do that?

There are good reasons to be cautious here. You're flying a nuclear reactor strapped to a bomb in front of a viewing deck.

Personally, I'd consider being about 1km away from a debris cloud propagating at 2km/s to be an OK distance. Consider that you have half a second to activate emergency protective systems... a set of safety radars might be able to trigger an explosively-closed blast-shutter fairly promptly, throwing up a curtain of rock and metal that could be as over-engineered as you saw fit.

> These ships fly themselves - to hit other structures they'd have to be quite off their final approach and their emergency systems would have to all fail. (I don't know that 'self-destruct' is the way to go in this case. Maybe...)

One possible scenario here is an uncontrolled descent onto the spaceport at de-orbit velocities, which is *also* going to be at about 2km/s, only there's going to be just one big lump of debris instead of an expanding cloud most of which will miss you.

The roof of the any of the buildings on the surface will probably be quite thick! You might consider that point defense systems (that after all, might be powerful fast tracking laser weapons that could present a serious threat to anything hundreds or even thousands of kilometres away) or [range safety systems](http://cn.cgwic.com/LaunchServices/Download/manual/Chapter%209%20Range%20Safety%20Control.pdf) that would allow someone to remotely destroy a ship, problematic for other reasons (especially for the owners and any passengers!) but then you're in the territory of viewing areas being too risky to allow.

There's also an additional problem you may want to consider.

A bang which throws up debris at 1-2km/s in a vacuum is going to throw that stuff a long, long way. A lot of it is going up and out, and it could pose a serious threat to anything in orbit. That's a reason why you have landing pads by the way, instead of landing on unimproved regolith, because otherwise the debris kicked up by your landing burn could trash the person behind you in your original orbit...

Comment: This is a really good answer. It now puts me in a dilemma, as I never considered the 'spaceship crashes into roof' scenario. I can now move all the launchpads several kilometers away and hope for the best, or redesign the habitats.

Comment: I've moved the pads. But I'm thinking of putting a 'crumple zone' on the roof of the hab, which is the vulnerable portion. If that can absorb enough of the initial impact, the rest of the hab can remain unchanged.

Comment: If you want them nearby, it will be a balance between safety, and logistics;  while putting them on the opposite side of the moon would be safest, you need to get people, supplies, fuel, air etc. to and from the launch pad.  Maybe put habitation somewhere safer and have a viewing area as some sort of command deck?

Answer (score 1):

**"This is for a game, this decision is for convenience of good visuals and game navigation."**

I found that in the comments.  That is key!  Leave the pad where it is.  Then when something blows up the players can see.  When it blows up real good it will mess with the base, knock stuff over, hole the windows etc.  Best - the players will see the flash and then see and hear the rain of stuff coming across and down.  No shockwave though being as it is the moon.

Stuff blowing up is one of the main reasons to play a game!  If nothing blows up you might as well stick to cribbage.

I love the idea of the crumple zone on the roof too.  Because a player might then survive having something big come down on the roof, then go out and survey the crumplage.  That is a French word I am pretty sure.

Comment: Clearly I have very mixed feelings about that because high realism is the main point of the game. So, I end up only being willing to accept unrealistic design to a small degree. Right now, I've moved the pads, but the crumple stuff is way too complicated and overkill and I abandoned that.

Comment: Sounds like your cribbage game needs some house rules.